# How do I use a variable as an index to an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a config file which has variables based on the domain of the page (HTTP_HOST)

`$c` is an array.
eg `$c['example.com-user']` is an entry in the config file.

I need to pass the value of `$c['example.com-user']` to a function building the variable name on the fly.

I have "example.com" in `$host` variable

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. I don't understand what you mean. Can you show some code? Also, what is $host and what does it have to do with the issue?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    $c['example.com-user'] = "someval";
    $host = "example.com";
    echo $c[ $host . '-user'];
?>
```

Tested, working.

Answer (score 1):

```
$c[$host.'-user']
```

Assuming you only ever need the config data for the current domain, might it be easier to have a config file per domain, rather than one monster array with all of them? Then you can just load up the relevant file at the start.

Comment: damn.. why didn't i think of this earlier

Answer (score 0):

If, for example your domain stored in variable `$host` and username in variable `$user`. Then, all you have to do is, use this variables as array's key:

```
echo $c[ $host . "-" . $user];
```

if `$host = 'inform.com'` and `$user = 'simple_user'`, the code above will translate into:

```
echo $c['inform.com-simple_user'];
```

You see, to concatenate string, you use '.' (dot).